# xmlstarlet failed to load external entity

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

My script is a simple one-liner that uses curl to get a URL with xml output. I'm trying to output only the text in the following tag:

```
<TEXT>No Hosts Queued for Purging</TEXT>
```

My script:

```
curl -u username:password -H 'X-Requested-With:QualysApiExplorer' 'https://qualysapi.qualys.com:443/api/2.0/fo/asset/host/' -d "action=purge&ips=$1&" | xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/BATCH_RETURN/RESPONSE/BATCH_LIST/BATCH/TEXT' -v "."
```

The curl output looks like this when not using xmlstarlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE BATCH_RETURN SYSTEM "https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/batch_return.dtd">
<BATCH_RETURN>
  <RESPONSE>
    <DATETIME>2017-04-20T20:27:15Z</DATETIME>
    <BATCH_LIST>
      <BATCH>
        <CODE>1921</CODE>
        <TEXT>No Hosts Queued for Purging</TEXT>
      </BATCH>
    </BATCH_LIST>
  </RESPONSE>
</BATCH_RETURN>
```

I get the following error when using xmlstarlet:

```
failed to load external entity "https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/batch_return.dtd"
TYPE BATCH_RETURN SYSTEM "https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/batch_return.dtd"
                                                                               ^
```

Comment: One thing worth mentioning is if your query returns nothing, this message might make you think there was something wrong with your XML. It is a **warning**, not a fatal error. It might simply be that you made a mistake in your use of `xmlstarlet sel`. In my case, I had used `-m` incorrectly (forgetting the `-v`), resulting in no output.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `fo -D` to remove the doctype before performing the query (`sel`) :

```
xml fo --help
XMLStarlet Toolkit: Format XML document
Usage: xml fo [<options>] <xml-file>
where <options> are
   -D or --dropdtd             - remove the DOCTYPE of the input docs
```

The following would work :

```
curl -u username:password \
     -H 'X-Requested-With:QualysApiExplorer' \
     'https://qualysapi.qualys.com:443/api/2.0/fo/asset/host/' \
     -d "action=purge&ips=$1&" | \
     xmlstarlet fo -D | \
     xmlstarlet sel -t -v "BATCH_RETURN/RESPONSE/BATCH_LIST/BATCH/TEXT"
```